Pyflink 1.18 checkpointing (not starting from last checkpoint)
I’m using PyFlink (1.18v) on Kubernetes pods and want to ensure that checkpointing is enabled so that if a pod restarts, the process continues from the last checkpoint. I have configured checkpointing to write to an AWS S3 bucket, and it appears to be working. However, after killing a pod, the process does not resume from the last checkpoint, leading to missing data in the Kafka stream after the pod restarts.
How can I resolve this issue?
Code:
# Set up the streaming execution environment
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env.set_parallelism(1)
env.set_stream_time_characteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

# checkpoint
env.enable_checkpointing(60*1000, CheckpointingMode.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
# Configure the checkpoint storage to S3
s3_checkpoint_path = CheckpointStorage("s3://xxx/flink-checkpoints")
env.get_checkpoint_config().set_checkpoint_storage(s3_checkpoint_path)

# Define Kafka consumer properties
kafka_consumer_properties = {
    "bootstrap.servers": self.kafka_host,
    "group.id": "xxx_group",
    "security.protocol": "PLAINTEXT"
}

# Create a Kafka consumer
kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
    topics=[
        "topic-1", 
        "topic-2"
    ],
    deserialization_schema=SimpleStringSchema(),
    properties=kafka_consumer_properties
)
kafka_consumer.set_commit_offsets_on_checkpoints(True)
kafka_consumer.set_start_from_latest()

watermark_strategy = (
    WatermarkStrategy.for_monotonous_timestamps().with_timestamp_assigner(
        self.CustomTimestampAssigner()
    )
)

# Add the Kafka consumer as a source to the Flink job
stream = env.add_source(kafka_consumer) \
    .map(self._decrypt_and_unpickle_message) \
    .filter(lambda x: x is not None) \
    .map(self.NormalizeMap(self)) \
    .assign_timestamps_and_watermarks(watermark_strategy) \
    .key_by(lambda record: record.get("_dwh_table_name"), key_type=Types.STRING()) \
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1))) \
    .process(self.Sink(self))

stream.print()

# Execute the Flink job
env.execute("Kafka Flink Streaming Job")


You killed a TaskManager pod? Did you try starting from committed offset?
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#starting-offset
KafkaSource.builder()
  // Start from committed offset of the consuming group, without reset strategy
  .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets())

For JobManager pod, the solution is K8S HA:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/deployment/ha/kubernetes_ha/#configuration
